# Edit image pixel by pixel - Python

Tags: python, image

I have two images, one overlay and one background.
I want to create a new image, by editing overlay image and manipulating it to show only the pixels which have blue colour in the background image. 
I dont want to add the background, it is only for selecting the pixels.
Rest part should be transparent.
Any hints or ideas please? PS: I edited result image with paint so its not perfect.

Image 1 is background image.

Image 2 is overlay image.

Image 3 is the check I want to perform. (to find out which pixels have blue in background and making remaining pixels transparent)

Image 4 is the result image after editing.

[image: background][image: overlay][image: check][image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed your images according to my way of thinking, so I took this as `image.png`:

[image]

and this as `mask.png`:

[image]

Then I did what I think you want as follows. I wrote it quite verbosely so you can see all the steps along the way:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open input images
image = Image.open("image.png")
mask  = Image.open("mask.png")

# Get dimensions
h,w=image.size

# Resize mask to match image, taking care not to introduce new colours (Image.NEAREST)
mask = mask.resize((h,w), Image.NEAREST)    
mask.save('mask_resized.png')

# Convert both images to numpy equivalents
npimage = np.array(image)
npmask  = np.array(mask)

# Make image transparent where mask is not blue
# Blue pixels in mask seem to show up as RGB(163 204 255)
npimage[:,:,3] = np.where((npmask[:,:,0]<170) & (npmask[:,:,1]<210) & (npmask[:,:,2]>250),255,0).astype(np.uint8)

# Identify grey pixels in image, i.e. R=G=B, and make transparent also
RequalsG=np.where(npimage[:,:,0]==npimage[:,:,1],1,0)
RequalsB=np.where(npimage[:,:,0]==npimage[:,:,2],1,0)
grey=(RequalsG*RequalsB).astype(np.uint8)
npimage[:,:,3] *= 1-grey

# Convert numpy image to PIL image and save
PILrgba=Image.fromarray(npimage)
PILrgba.save("result.png")
```

And this is the result:

[image]

---

**Notes:**

a) Your image already has an (unused) alpha channel present.

b) Any lines starting:

```
npimage[:,:,3] = ...
```

are just modifying the 4th channel, i.e. the alpha/transparency channel of the image